# How to solve request timed out?  And why am I getting this error? 

Tags: router, internet-connection, ping, traceroute

I am having issue with my net connection. My net connection gets disconnected at times. Online gaming faces lagging issue.

It was 1st noted after modem firmware was updated by the ISP (airtel-broadband). And I am not sure what is causing this net issue. I am having a netgear WIFI router(but my machine is connected to router through cable) and a Beetel 110TC1 modem (cable only).

All the firewall are disabled from pc , router, modem is Windows XP SP3.

I tried setting static ip to my router(192.168.1.2) with respect to Modem(192.168.1.1) - the configuration was successful but the problem still exists about the lag.

Then I tried setting DMZ for my modem. But the configuration was a failure as my internet was totally blocked.

**Data collected from my machine**

This is my ping statistics to google.com

**data 1**

```
Ping statistics for 74.125.236.48:
    Packets: Sent = 50, Received = 49, Lost = 1 (2% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 27ms, Maximum = 229ms, Average = 94ms
```

**data 2**

```
Ping statistics for 74.125.236.51:
    Packets: Sent = 100, Received = 94, Lost = 6 (6% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 28ms, Maximum = 280ms, Average = 93ms
```

How do we read this data from **trace route**?

**data 1**

```
Tracing route to www.l.google.com [74.125.236.51]
over a maximum of 40 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.1          router ip
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1       modem ip
  3     *       81 ms    86 ms  [122.179.1.1]     
  4     *      165 ms    27 ms  [60.93.226.79]
  5    27 ms    65 ms    97 ms  61.95.240.129
  6     *      102 ms   126 ms  182.79.252.182
  7   145 ms   189 ms   281 ms  72.14.223.145
  8     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  9     *       50 ms    90 ms  209.85.241.33
 10   116 ms    89 ms     *     74.125.236.51
 11   108 ms    34 ms    35 ms  74.125.236.51

Trace complete.
```

**data 2**

```
Tracing route to www.l.google.com [74.125.236.80]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.1
  2    <1 ms    <1 ms     1 ms  192.168.1.1
  3     *        *       82 ms  [122.179.1.1]
  4     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  5     *      122 ms     *     61.95.240.129
  6     *       33 ms    29 ms  182.79.252.182
  7     *      102 ms   115 ms  72.14.223.145
  8   162 ms   170 ms     *     66.249.94.168
  9     *        *      154 ms  209.85.249.235
 10   162 ms    88 ms   109 ms  74.125.236.80

Trace complete.
```

**data 3**

```
Tracing route to www.l.google.com [74.125.236.80]
over a maximum of 30 hops:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  10.0.0.1
  2     1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.1.1
  3     *       77 ms    76 ms  [122.179.1.1]
  4   162 ms   115 ms   135 ms  [60.93.226.79]
  5   104 ms   176 ms   122 ms  61.95.240.129
  6     *        *        *     Request timed out.
  7     *        *       42 ms  72.14.223.145
  8    92 ms    56 ms    31 ms  66.249.94.168
  9     *       73 ms    53 ms  209.85.249.235
 10   157 ms    51 ms    28 ms  74.125.236.80

Trace complete.
```

will we be able to resolve something from tracert about my ping issue?

Comment: You haven't said *what your issue is*! There's no obvious problem with anything you posted.

Comment: @carlF i face lagging issue at games. while browsing at times the pages get long time to load. though my network speed is 2mbps.

Comment: @Babu From your traceroute results, the bottleneck doesn't seem to be at your local area network. You might want to switch your firewall back on and contact your ISP to get a line quality check.

Comment: @jin what are the 3 columns of time shown in traceroute?

Comment: @Babu They refer to the time taken for a single hop between each host from you to the destination.

Comment: @jin will this tracerouter issue explain ping test results. Since all the time traceroute test completed, even though some server gave request time out in traceroute. I am trying to attain more details from your observation, since I would like to give the right info to the ISP. They are a bit reluctant in accepting problems a bit complicated :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

72.14.223.145 would appear to be a Google router. If the timeouts are happening in Google's network, there is not much you can do about it, but Google being who they are they'll likely fix the problem very quickly. Google cares deeply about network speeds.

If the problem is actually happening at 61.95.240.129 or its sister IP addresses, that's Airtel, an Indian ISP. I would expect them to respond quickly as well, because they will lose both paying customers and network peers if their network isn't functioning well. You might notify them.

The problem definitely is *not* in your own network or router or modem.

Comment: the issue is solved. the issue was with airtel. Though i had to fight for a week. finally got it done. Phew!! thanks